# Micro-refactoring: creating a hash for JSON from objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey, thanks in advance for the help.

I have another pretty straight forward question.
This isn't very rails-like, but it works. Is there a way to do it better? I know there's group_by, for dates, but I can't figure out how to use it for this.
I'm still super new at ruby, but know enough to tell that there must be a better way!

```
def self.getRecipeNames
   recipes = Recipe.all
   names = Hash.new
   recipes.each do |recipe|
      names[recipe.id] = recipe.name
   end
   names
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` (`inject` in older version of Ruby) to transform your list of recipes to single hash (that's why it is reduce, it reduces to single value, which can be list/hash/whatever):

```
recipes = Recipe.all
names = recipes.reduce({}) do |acc,el|
  acc[el.id] = el.name
  acc 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is prettier (IMO), but possibly not as efficient as your original method (or MBO's).

```
def self.getRecipeNames
  Hash[Recipe.all.map{|r| [r.id, r.name] }]
end
```

This uses the fact that `Hash::[]` takes an array of key/value pairs, e.g. `Hash[[:a, 1], [:b, 2]] => { :a => 1, :b => 2 }`.

**Edit:** Actually I'm sure this is half as efficient as both your original method and MBO's, because both `Array#map` and `Hash::[]` iterate through the whole array. So it's pretty, but don't use it if you have e.g. thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the Recipe model, use `:select`

```
def self.getRecipeNames
  find(:all, :select => 'id, name')
end
```

controller:

```
@names = Recipe.getRecipeNames  
@names.to_json # etc.
```